# Running docker build based on argument

Tags: docker, dockerfile

Dockerfile:

```
ARG arg
FROM main-registry.gitlab.com/base/folder/:{$arg}

specific conda environment file to use
ARG conda_environment=environment.yml

COPY . .

RUN conda update --quiet conda
```

I need to replace this $arg with the value provided in the build command:

```
docker build --build-arg arg="image_id" -t hello .
```

I am getting the arg correctly but I am not able to replace the value of the argument in url.

Ideal case:

> new url = url/image_id

Reality:

> new url = url/$arg

Comment: Can you please post an actual unedited snippet or all of your Dockerfile? Your syntax seems wrong with the `{}` from what you originally posted. Seems like it should be `FROM url/${arg}` instead

Comment: ARG arg
FROM main-registry.gitlab.com/base/folder/:{$arg}

# specific conda environment file to use
ARG conda_environment=environment.yml

COPY . .

RUN conda update --quiet conda

Comment: can you please edit your post instead of posting this in a comment? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've done this before.

In your Dockerfile, you can have `ARG` commands before your initial `FROM` e.g. The following is taken from one of my Dockerfile templates (for ASP.NET Core multi-stage docker build):

```
ARG BUILD_IMAGE_TAG
ARG RUNTIME_IMAGE_TAG

FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/core/sdk:${BUILD_IMAGE_TAG} AS build

...

FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/core/aspnet:${RUNTIME_IMAGE_TAG} AS runtime

...
```

I suspect you've just got the syntax slightly wrong; `{$arg}` should be `${arg}` as per my example above.

Comment: Thanks it worked. I was missing the : and was giving /.